# ANOVA 3 factors: 2 fixed factors, 1 factor nested within crossed fixed factors

Tags: mixed-model, anova, experiment-design, fixed-effects-model, nested-data

I have a dilema of the suitability of the analysis with my design.
I have 3 fixed factors:
- Photoperiod (2 levels: 16L8D; 10L14D)
- Temperature (2 levels: 6ºC; 25ºC)
- Time (4 levels: 50;70;90;150 days)

Photoperiod and Temperature are crossed, and Time is nested within the crossed factors. See this image:

[image]

I have tried the following ANOVA nested model: (Y: dependent variable; df: dataframe)

```
aov(Y ~ (Photoperiod * Temperature) + Error((Photoperiod * Temperature)/Time), data=df)
```

And I get that results:

```
Call:
aov(formula = Y ~ (Photoperiod * Temperature) + 
    Error((Photoperiod * Temperature)/Time), data=df)

Grand Mean: 4.492955

Stratum 1: Photoperiod

Terms:
                 Photoperiod
Sum of Squares  197.7843
Deg. of Freedom        1

1 out of 2 effects not estimable
Estimated effects are balanced

Stratum 2: Temperature

Terms:
                Temperature
Sum of Squares   3795.089
Deg. of Freedom         1

1 out of 2 effects not estimable
Estimated effects are balanced

Stratum 3: Photoperiod:Temperature

Terms:
                Photoperiod:Temperature
Sum of Squares           197.7843
Deg. of Freedom                 1

Estimated effects are balanced

Stratum 4: Photoperiod:Temperature:Time

Terms:
                Residuals
Sum of Squares   626.4977
Deg. of Freedom         2

Residual standard error: 17.69884

Stratum 5: Within

Terms:
                Residuals
Sum of Squares   30658.85
Deg. of Freedom       182

Residual standard error: 12.97903
```

I don't know if this approach is right, and how can I get p-values from those results.

Answer (score 10):

Based on the image you uploaded, I don't think you have a nested structure. You seem to have all combinations of Photoperiod, Temperature and Time, which would make this a full factorial experiment. That makes this very simple to analyze - you just need a basic linear model with lm(Y ~ Photoperiod * Temperature * Time). If I were you, though, I would probably only analyse the interactions you had specific hypotheses for instead of all the terms in that model (to avoid chasing noise).

Comment: Thank you user5151349!

Actually I was about doing the basic linear model you tell me, but I realized that there is no independence between Time levels because there were physically in the same climate chamber; i.e., I had 4 climate chambers (25ºC 16L8D, 25ºC 10L14D, 6ºC 16L8D, 6ºC 10L14D) and the some of the individuals inside where removed at t=50, others at t=70, others at t=90 and the last ones at t=150. That is why I though I had a kind of split-plot design, but not exactly. Am I wrong?

Thank you again in advance

Comment: This relates to a long debate on pseudoreplication, and climate chambers tend to be a somewhat grey area. While it is important to think about, there are limits at which its application becomes technically correct but practically insignificant (Thought experiment: are multiple plots in the same field pseudoreplicated? Same forest? Same region? Where's the boundary?). To cut a long story short, what you are proposing makes sense, but 1) I think it is common to treat this as a full factorial anyway, and 2) I would be very surprised if you got a different answer.

Comment: But if you do want to go down this road, I would check out lmer in package lme4 .

Comment: If there is only 1 climate chamber per photoperiod/temperature combination, there is no way in any event to untangle any specific climate-chamber influence from its associated photoperiod and temperature combination. So it's not clear what is to be gained from anything other than a factorial analysis. Also, the OP should note that calling `summary(aov(...))` provides more information than the default `aov()` output on the console.

Comment: Good point, @EdM, I should have been clearer about that.

Comment: Hi mkt and EdM, thank you very much for your comments. I think this model would fit well with my data: Hd.model<-lmer(log(Y+1) ~ Photoperiod + Time + Temperature + (1|subject), data=df) as Y are the eggs laid by several subjects and they were randomly distributed between the different situations, so there is no real independence within the data. I take log transformation because it gives a better residual plot.

Comment: @mjrs You're welcome, and good luck. 

I'm not a huge fan of the log(x + constant) approach, since the choice of constant can affect your results; you could use a different error distribution instead. But it is a common approach and should work in many, perhaps most, situations. 

Besides that, the only comment I have is that you are now assuming no interactions at all. Given your variables, I find that difficult to believe.

Comment: Yes, indeed mkt, I have forgotten the interactions. Now I have included them and the results seem coherent. Thank you a lot!